# Javascript [Object object] error in for loop while appending string

Tags: javascript, object

I am a novice  trying to deserialize my result from an onSuccess function as :

```
 "onResultHttpService": function (result, properties) {
  var json_str = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(result);
  var data = [];
  var categoryField = properties.PodAttributes.categoryField;
  var valueField = properties.PodAttributes.valueField;
  for (var i in json_str) {                   
       var serie = new Array(json_str[i] + '.' + categoryField, json_str[i] +     '.' + valueField);
                data.push(serie);
       }
```

The JSON in `result` looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Text": "INDIRECT GOODS AND SERVICES",
        "Spend": 577946097.51
    },
    {
        "Text": "LOGISTICS",
        "Spend": 242563225.05
    }
]
```

As you can see i am appending the string in for loop..The reason i am doing is because the property names keep on changing therefore i cannot just write it as

```
 var serie = new Array(json_str[i].propName, json_str[i].propValue);
```

I need to pass the data (array type) to bind a highchart columnchart. But the when i check the var serie it shows as

```
serie[0] = [object Object].Text
serie[1] = [object Object].Spend
```

Why do i not get the actual content getting populated inside the array?

Comment: Since your question really hinges on the data you're looping over, it would be good to show us that data (e.g., what does `result` look like?).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, here it is result = [{"Text":"INDIRECT GOODS AND SERVICES","Spend":577946097.51},{"Text":"LOGISTICS","Spend":242563225.05}]   // After desiarilization it becomes..var json_str = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(result); i.e json_str = json_str[0]..json_str[1]

Comment: To improve your question, use the "edit" link under it.

Comment: I went ahead and edited it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that because `json_str[i]` is an object, and that's what happens when you coerce an object into a string (unless the object implements `toString` in a useful way, which this one clearly doesn't). <s>You haven't shown the JSON you're deserializing...</s>

Now that you've posted the JSON, we can see that it's an array containing two objects, each of which has a `Text` and `Spend` property. So in your loop, `json_str[i].Text` will refer to the `Text` property. If you want to retrieve that property using the name in `categoryField`, you can do that via `json_str[i][categoryField]`.

I don't know what you want to end up with in `serie`, but if you want it to be a two-slot array where the first contains the value of the category field and the second contains the value of the spend field, then

```
var serie = [json_str[i][categoryField], json_str[i][valueField]];
```

(There's almost never a reason to use `new Array`, just use array literals — `[...]` — instead.)